# Libgdx socket.io enemy movement only appears on the first connected client

Tags: javascript, java, node.js, socket.io, libgdx

I'm building a mmorpg in Libgdx with socket.io(with node.js).I'm trying to create enemies(monsters, skeletons etc.).I created a monster class and it working for singleplayer but I'm trying to move these enemies correctly on each online player.When I run this code, it creates enemies on all clients, but when enemies move, no action appears on clients.So I need to send each monster's positions to the server and get these positions in every client, but I don't know exactly how to do it.

My GameScreen code:

```
public class GameScreen implements Screen {

    private final float UPDATE_TIME = 1/60f;
    float timer;
    private Socket socket;
    String id;
    Player player;
    Texture playerTex;
    Texture friendlyPlayerTex;
    Texture monsterTex;
    HashMap<String, FriendlyPlayer> friendlyPlayers;
    HashMap<String, MPMonster> monsters;
    private Multiplayer game;
    TiledMap tiledMap;
    OrthographicCamera camera;
    private Viewport gamePort;
    TiledMapRenderer tiledMapRenderer;
    private Hud hud;
    private World world;
    private Box2DDebugRenderer box2DDebugRenderer;
    private BitmapFont usernameFont;
    private Monster monster;

    public GameScreen(Multiplayer game) {
        this.game = game;

        Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(null);

        playerTex = new Texture("player.png");
        friendlyPlayerTex = new Texture("player.png");
        monsterTex = new Texture("agent.png");

        friendlyPlayers = new HashMap<String, FriendlyPlayer>();
        monsters = new HashMap<String, MPMonster>();

        float w = Gdx.graphics.getWidth() / Multiplayer.PPM;
        float h = Gdx.graphics.getHeight() / Multiplayer.PPM;

        camera = new OrthographicCamera();
        camera.setToOrtho(false,w,h);
        camera.update();

        tiledMap = new TmxMapLoader().load("maps/newmap.tmx");
        tiledMapRenderer = new OrthogonalTiledMapRenderer(tiledMap, 1 / Multiplayer.PPM);

        world = new World(new Vector2(0, 0), true);
        box2DDebugRenderer = new Box2DDebugRenderer();

        new B2DWorldCreator(world, tiledMap);

        gamePort = new FitViewport(Multiplayer.V_WIDTH / Multiplayer.PPM, Multiplayer.V_HEIGHT / Multiplayer.PPM, camera);

        hud = new Hud(game.batch);

        usernameFont = new BitmapFont(Gdx.files.internal("pixthulhu/raw/font-export.fnt"));
        usernameFont.setUseIntegerPositions(false);
        usernameFont.getData().setScale(1 / 140f);
        usernameFont.setColor(Color.WHITE);

        //monster = new Monster(700, 800, 28, 32, monsterTex, world);

        connectSocket();
        configSocketEvents();
    }

    public void updateServer(float dt) {
        timer += dt;
        if(timer >= UPDATE_TIME && player != null && player.hasMoved()) {
            JSONObject data = new JSONObject();
            try {
                data.put("x", player.getX());
                data.put("y", player.getY());
                data.put("vx", player.body.getLinearVelocity().x);
                data.put("vy", player.body.getLinearVelocity().y);
                data.put("bx", player.body.getPosition().x);
                data.put("by", player.body.getPosition().y);
                data.put("username", player.username);
                socket.emit("playerMoved", data);
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                Gdx.app.log("SOCKET.IO", "Error sending update data!");
            }
        }

        if(timer >= UPDATE_TIME && monster != null && monster.hasMoved()) {
            JSONObject data = new JSONObject();
            try {
                data.put("x", monster.getX());
                data.put("y", monster.getY());
                data.put("vx", monster.body.getLinearVelocity().x);
                data.put("vy", monster.body.getLinearVelocity().y);
                data.put("bx", monster.body.getPosition().x);
                data.put("by", monster.body.getPosition().y);
                socket.emit("monsterMoved", data);
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                Gdx.app.log("SOCKET.IO", "Error sending update data!");
            }
        }
    }

    public void handleInput(){
        if(Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Input.Keys.Y)) {
            camera.zoom += 0.1f;
        } else if(Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Input.Keys.H)) {
            camera.zoom -= 0.1f;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void render (float delta) {
        handleInput();
        updateServer(Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime());

        world.step(1/60f, 6, 2);

        Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 1);
        Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

        tiledMapRenderer.setView(camera);
        tiledMapRenderer.render();

        box2DDebugRenderer.render(world, camera.combined);

        game.batch.setProjectionMatrix(camera.combined);
        game.batch.begin();

        if(player != null){
            player.update(delta);
            player.draw(game.batch);
            player.handleInput();
        }

        if(monster != null) {
            monster.update(delta);
            monster.draw(game.batch);
            monster.chase(player);
        }

        camera.update();

        for(HashMap.Entry<String, FriendlyPlayer> entry : friendlyPlayers.entrySet()){
            //entry.getValue().update(delta);/////////////!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
            entry.getValue().draw(game.batch);
            entry.getValue().setPosition();
            usernameFont.draw(game.batch, entry.getValue().username, entry.getValue().bx - 15 / Multiplayer.PPM, entry.getValue().by + 38 / Multiplayer.PPM);
        }

        for(HashMap.Entry<String, MPMonster> entry : monsters.entrySet()){
            entry.getValue().draw(game.batch);
            //entry.getValue().update(delta);
        }

        game.batch.end();

        game.batch.setProjectionMatrix(hud.stage.getCamera().combined);
        hud.stage.draw();
    }

    public void connectSocket(){
        try {
            socket = IO.socket("http://localhost:8080");
            socket.connect();
        } catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }
    public void configSocketEvents(){
        socket.on(Socket.EVENT_CONNECT, new Emitter.Listener() {
            @Override
            public void call(Object... args) {
                Gdx.app.log("SocketIO", "Connected");
                player = new Player(playerTex, world, camera);
                monster = new Monster(700, 800, 28, 32, monsterTex, world);
            }
        }).on("socketID", new Emitter.Listener() {
            @Override
            public void call(Object... args) {
                JSONObject data = (JSONObject) args[0];
                try {
                    id = data.getString("id");
                    Gdx.app.log("SocketIO", "My ID: " + id);
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    Gdx.app.log("SocketIO", "Error getting ID");
                }
            }
        }).on("newPlayer", new Emitter.Listener() {
            @Override
            public void call(Object... args) {
                JSONObject data = (JSONObject) args[0];
                try {
                    String playerId = data.getString("id");
                    Gdx.app.log("SocketIO", "New Player Connect: " + id);
                    friendlyPlayers.put(playerId, new FriendlyPlayer(friendlyPlayerTex, world, game));
                }catch(JSONException e){
                    Gdx.app.log("SocketIO", "Error getting New PlayerID");
                }
            }
        }).on("playerDisconnected", new Emitter.Listener() {
            @Override
            public void call(Object... args) {
                JSONObject data = (JSONObject) args[0];
                try {
                    id = data.getString("id");
                    friendlyPlayers.remove(id);
                }catch(JSONException e){
                    Gdx.app.log("SocketIO", "Error getting disconnected PlayerID");
                }
            }
        }).on("playerMoved", new Emitter.Listener() {
            @Override
            public void call(Object... args) {
                JSONObject data = (JSONObject) args[0];
                try {
                    //SEND STATE AND BOX2D
                    String playerId = data.getString("id");
                    Double x = data.getDouble("x");
                    Double y = data.getDouble("y");
                    Double vx = data.getDouble("vx");
                    Double vy = data.getDouble("vy");
                    Double bx = data.getDouble("bx");
                    Double by = data.getDouble("by");
                    String username = data.getString("username");
                    if(friendlyPlayers.get(playerId) != null) {
                        friendlyPlayers.get(playerId).setPosition(x.floatValue(), y.floatValue());
                        friendlyPlayers.get(playerId).vx = vx.floatValue();
                        friendlyPlayers.get(playerId).vy = vy.floatValue();
                        friendlyPlayers.get(playerId).bx = bx.floatValue();
                        friendlyPlayers.get(playerId).by = by.floatValue();
                        friendlyPlayers.get(playerId).username = username;
                        friendlyPlayers.get(playerId).update(Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime());
                    }
                }catch(JSONException e){
                }
            }
        }).on("getPlayers", new Emitter.Listener() {
            @Override
            public void call(Object... args) {
                JSONArray objects = (JSONArray) args[0];
                try {
                    for(int i = 0; i < objects.length(); i++){
                        /////GET STATE AND SET TO COOP PLAYER
                        FriendlyPlayer coopPlayer = new FriendlyPlayer(friendlyPlayerTex, world, game);
                        Vector2 position = new Vector2();
                        Float vx, vy;
                        Float bx, by;
                        String username;
                        position.x = ((Double) objects.getJSONObject(i).getDouble("x")).floatValue();
                        position.y = ((Double) objects.getJSONObject(i).getDouble("y")).floatValue();
                        vx = ((Double) objects.getJSONObject(i).getDouble("vx")).floatValue();
                        vy = ((Double) objects.getJSONObject(i).getDouble("vy")).floatValue();
                        bx = ((Double) objects.getJSONObject(i).getDouble("bx")).floatValue();
                        by = ((Double) objects.getJSONObject(i).getDouble("by")).floatValue();
                        username = objects.getJSONObject(i).getString("username");
                        coopPlayer.setPosition(position.x, position.y);
                        coopPlayer.vx = vx;
                        coopPlayer.vy = vy;
                        coopPlayer.bx = bx;
                        coopPlayer.by = by;
                        coopPlayer.username = username;
                        friendlyPlayers.put(objects.getJSONObject(i).getString("id"), coopPlayer);
                        coopPlayer.update(Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime());
                    }
                } catch(JSONException e){

                }
            }
        }).on("newMonster", new Emitter.Listener() {
            @Override
            public void call(Object... args) {
                JSONObject data = (JSONObject) args[0];
                try {
                    String monsterId = data.getString("id");
                    monsters.put(monsterId, new MPMonster(700, 800, 28, 32, monsterTex, world));
                }catch(JSONException e){
                    Gdx.app.log("SocketIO", "Error creating new monster");
                }
            }
        }).on("monsterMoved", new Emitter.Listener() {
            @Override
            public void call(Object... args) {
                JSONObject data = (JSONObject) args[0];
                try {
                    String playerId = data.getString("pid");
                    String monsterId = data.getString("id");
                    Double x = data.getDouble("x");
                    Double y = data.getDouble("y");
                    Double vx = data.getDouble("vx");
                    Double vy = data.getDouble("vy");
                    Double bx = data.getDouble("bx");
                    Double by = data.getDouble("by");
                    if(monsters.get(monsterId) != null) {
                        monsters.get(monsterId).setPosition(x.floatValue(), y.floatValue());
                        monsters.get(monsterId).vx = vx.floatValue();
                        monsters.get(monsterId).vy = vy.floatValue();
                        monsters.get(monsterId).bx = bx.floatValue();
                        monsters.get(monsterId).by = by.floatValue();
                        monsters.get(monsterId).update(Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime());
                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {

                }
            }
        }).on("getMonsters", new Emitter.Listener() {
            @Override
            public void call(Object... args) {
                JSONArray objects = (JSONArray) args[0];
                try {
                    for(int i = 0; i < objects.length(); i++){
                        /////GET STATE AND SET TO COOP PLAYER
                        MPMonster monster = new MPMonster(700, 800, 28, 32, monsterTex, world);
                        Vector2 position = new Vector2();
                        Float vx, vy;
                        Float bx, by;
                        position.x = ((Double) objects.getJSONObject(i).getDouble("x")).floatValue();
                        position.y = ((Double) objects.getJSONObject(i).getDouble("y")).floatValue();
                        vx = ((Double) objects.getJSONObject(i).getDouble("vx")).floatValue();
                        vy = ((Double) objects.getJSONObject(i).getDouble("vy")).floatValue();
                        bx = ((Double) objects.getJSONObject(i).getDouble("bx")).floatValue();
                        by = ((Double) objects.getJSONObject(i).getDouble("by")).floatValue();
                        monster.setPosition(position.x, position.y);
                        monster.vx = vx;
                        monster.vy = vy;
                        monster.bx = bx;
                        monster.by = by;
                        monsters.put(objects.getJSONObject(i).getString("id"), monster);
                        //monsters.get(objects.getJSONObject(i).getString("id")).chase(player);
                        monsters.get(objects.getJSONObject(i).getString("id")).update(Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime());
                        //monster.update(Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime());
                    }
                } catch(JSONException e){

                }
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void show() {

    }

    @Override
    public void resize(int width, int height) {
        gamePort.update(width, height);
    }

    @Override
    public void pause() {

    }

    @Override
    public void resume() {

    }

    @Override
    public void hide() {

    }

    @Override
    public void dispose() {
        playerTex.dispose();
        friendlyPlayerTex.dispose();
    }
}
```

My Monster code:

```
public class Monster extends Sprite {
    private float x;
    private float y;
    private World world;
    private Vector2 previousPosition;
    public Body body;
    private TextureRegion monsterStand;

    public Monster(float x, float y, int w, int h, Texture texture, World world) {
        super(texture);
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.world = world;

        monsterStand = new TextureRegion(texture, 0, 0, w, h);

        setBounds(700 / Multiplayer.PPM, 800 / Multiplayer.PPM, 28 / Multiplayer.PPM, 32 / Multiplayer.PPM);
        monsterPhysics();
        setRegion(monsterStand);

        previousPosition = new Vector2(getX(), getY());
    }

    public void update(float dt) {
        setPosition(body.getPosition().x - getWidth() / 2, body.getPosition().y - getHeight() / 2);

        body.applyLinearImpulse(
                (0 - body.getLinearVelocity().x) * body.getMass(),
                (0 - body.getLinearVelocity().y) * body.getMass(),
                body.getWorldCenter().x, body.getWorldCenter().y, true
        );
    }

    public void chase(Player player) {
        float speedX = 0;
        float speedY = 0;

        if(Funcs.distance(body.getPosition(), player.body.getPosition()) <= 1.3f) {
            if(player.body.getPosition().x > body.getPosition().x) {
                speedX = 0.5f;
            } else if(player.body.getPosition().x < body.getPosition().x) {
                speedX = -0.5f;
            } else {
                speedX = 0f;
            }

            if(player.body.getPosition().y > body.getPosition().y) {
                speedY = 0.5f;
            } else if(player.body.getPosition().y < body.getPosition().y) {
                speedY = -0.5f;
            } else {
                speedY = 0f;
            }

            body.applyLinearImpulse(
                    (speedX - body.getLinearVelocity().x) * body.getMass(),
                    (speedY - body.getLinearVelocity().y) * body.getMass(),
                    body.getWorldCenter().x, body.getWorldCenter().y, true
            );
        }
    }

    private void monsterPhysics() {
        BodyDef bdef = new BodyDef();
        PolygonShape shape = new PolygonShape();
        FixtureDef fdef = new FixtureDef();

        Rectangle rect = getBoundingRectangle();

        bdef.type = BodyDef.BodyType.DynamicBody;
        bdef.position.set(700 / Multiplayer.PPM, 800 / Multiplayer.PPM);

        body = world.createBody(bdef);

        shape.setAsBox(rect.getWidth() / 2, rect.getHeight() / 2);

        fdef.shape = shape;

        body.createFixture(fdef);
    }

    public boolean hasMoved(){
        if(previousPosition.x != getX() || previousPosition.y != getY()){
            previousPosition.x = getX();
            previousPosition.y = getY();
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

I also have MPMonster class:

```
public class MPMonster extends Sprite {
    private float x;
    private float y;
    public float vx;
    public float vy;
    public float bx;
    public float by;
    private World world;
    private Vector2 previousPosition;
    public Body body;
    private TextureRegion monsterStand;

    public MPMonster(float x, float y, int w, int h, Texture texture, World world) {
        super(texture);
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.world = world;

        monsterStand = new TextureRegion(texture, 0, 0, w, h);

        setBounds(x / Multiplayer.PPM, y / Multiplayer.PPM, w / Multiplayer.PPM, h / Multiplayer.PPM);
        monsterPhysics();
        setRegion(monsterStand);

        previousPosition = new Vector2(getX(), getY());
    }

    public void update(float dt) {
        //setRegion(getFrame(dt));
        setPosition(body.getPosition().x - getWidth() / 2, body.getPosition().y - getHeight() / 2);
        body.setTransform(bx, by, 0);
    }

    public void chase(Player player) {
        float speedX = 0;
        float speedY = 0;

        if(Funcs.distance(body.getPosition(), player.body.getPosition()) <= 1.3f) {
            if(player.body.getPosition().x > body.getPosition().x) {
                speedX = 0.5f;
            } else if(player.body.getPosition().x < body.getPosition().x) {
                speedX = -0.5f;
            } else {
                speedX = 0f;
            }

            if(player.body.getPosition().y > body.getPosition().y) {
                speedY = 0.5f;
            } else if(player.body.getPosition().y < body.getPosition().y) {
                speedY = -0.5f;
            } else {
                speedY = 0f;
            }

            body.applyLinearImpulse(
                    (speedX - body.getLinearVelocity().x) * body.getMass(),
                    (speedY - body.getLinearVelocity().y) * body.getMass(),
                    body.getWorldCenter().x, body.getWorldCenter().y, true
            );
        }
    }

    private void monsterPhysics() {
        BodyDef bdef = new BodyDef();
        PolygonShape shape = new PolygonShape();
        FixtureDef fdef = new FixtureDef();

        Rectangle rect = getBoundingRectangle();

        bdef.type = BodyDef.BodyType.DynamicBody;
        bdef.position.set(x / Multiplayer.PPM, y / Multiplayer.PPM);

        body = world.createBody(bdef);

        shape.setAsBox(rect.getWidth() / 2, rect.getHeight() / 2);

        fdef.shape = shape;

        body.createFixture(fdef);
    }

    public boolean hasMoved(){
        if(previousPosition.x != getX() || previousPosition.y != getY()){
            previousPosition.x = getX();
            previousPosition.y = getY();
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

And my server code:

```
var app = require('express')();
var server = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(server);
var players = [];
var monsters = [];

server.listen(8080, function(){
    console.log("Server is now running...");
});

io.on('connection', function(socket){
    console.log("Player Connected!");
    monsterID = ID();
    socket.emit('socketID', { id: socket.id });
    socket.emit('getPlayers', players);
    socket.emit('getMonsters', monsters);
    socket.broadcast.emit('newPlayer', { id: socket.id });
    socket.broadcast.emit('newMonster', { id: monsterID });
    socket.on('playerMoved', function(data) {
        data.id = socket.id;
        socket.broadcast.emit('playerMoved', data);

        for(var i = 0; i < players.length; i++) {
            if(players[i].id == data.id) {
                players[i].username = data.username;
                players[i].x = data.x;
                players[i].y = data.y;
                players[i].vx = data.vx;
                players[i].vy = data.vy;
                players[i].bx = data.bx;
                players[i].by = data.by;
            }
        }
    });
    socket.on('monsterMoved', function(data) {
        data.id = monsterID;
        data.pid = socket.id;
        socket.broadcast.emit('monsterMoved', data);

        for(var i = 0; i < monsters.length; i++) {
            if(monsters[i].id == data.id) {
                monsters[i].x = data.x;
                monsters[i].y = data.y;
                monsters[i].vx = data.vx;
                monsters[i].vy = data.vy;
                monsters[i].bx = data.bx;
                monsters[i].by = data.by;
            }
        }
    });
    socket.on('disconnect', function(){
        console.log("Player Disconnected");
        socket.broadcast.emit('playerDisconnected', { id: socket.id });
        for(var i = 0; i < players.length; i++){
            if(players[i].id == socket.id){
                players.splice(i, 1);
            }
        }
    });
    players.push(new player(socket.id, "", 900 / 100, 600 / 100, 0, 0, 0, 0));
    monsters.push(new monster(monsterID, 700 / 100, 800 / 100, 0, 0, 700 / 100, 800 / 100));
});

function player(id, username, x, y, vx, vy, bx, by){
    this.id = id;
    this.username = username;
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.vx = vx;
    this.vy = vy;
    this.bx = bx;
    this.by = by;
}

function monster(id, x, y, vx, vy, bx, by) {
    this.id = id;
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.vx = vx;
    this.vy = vy;
    this.bx = bx;
    this.by = by;
}

var ID = function () {
    return Math.random().toString().substr(2, 9);
  };
```

Comment: What is your exact question? Do you get an error on your code?

Comment: When I run this code, it creates enemies on all clients, but when enemies move, only the first connected client can see the monster movement.

Comment: The code is a bit much to look at, and most is probably unrelated to your problem. Can you reduce it? I guess only the connection and message sending/receiving parts should be relevant.

Comment: Please also add if your problem is only related to the `monsterMoved` parts. All other messages work fine (e.g. is playerMoved visible to all clients)?